# keyword "auto" C++ and "dynamic" C#

Tags: c#, c++, dynamic, syntax, reference

Does "dynamic" keyword in C# work like "auto" in C++

More details:

`auto a = 5; //C++`

`dynamic a = 5; //C#`

Are they similar?

Comment: `auto` resolves at compile time, whereas `dynamic` is at runtime.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

NO, they are not similar. AFAIK, `auto` would be similar to `var` in C#.

`auto` gets resolved to compile time, not runtime.

FROM MSDN

> The auto keyword directs the compiler to use the initialization
>   expression of a declared variable to deduce its type.

So in your code

```
auto a = 5; //C++
a.ToUpper(); // Compile time error
```

But

```
dynamic a = 5; //C# 
a.ToUpper(); //No error at compile time since it will resolve @ runtime
```

But at run time it will throw an error since `int` type has no `ToUpper()` method

Answer (score 16):

No.

The equivalent of `auto` in C# is `var` - the compiler will deduce the appropriate type. `dynamic` is determined at runtime, so it will never throw compile errors. From MSDN:

"At compile time, an element that is typed as dynamic is assumed to support any operation."

It will however throw errors at runtime if the code is invalid.